# Automating jobs on remote servers with python2.7

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, ssh, automation

I need to make a python script that will do these steps in order, but I'm not sure how to go about setting this up.

- SSH into a server
- Copy a folder from point A to point B (cp /foo/bar/folder1 /foo/folder2)
- mysql -u root -pfoobar (This database is accessible from localhost only)

  create a database, do some other mysql stuff in the mysql console
- Replaces instances of Foo with Bar in file foobar
- Copy and edit a file
- Restart a service

The fact that I have to ssh into a server, and THEN do all of this is really confusing me. I looked into the Fabric library, but that seems to do only do 1 command at a time and doesn't keep context from previous commands.

Answer (score 1):

> I looked into the Fabric library, but that seems to do only do 1 command at a time and doesn't keep context from previous commands.

Look into Fabric more. It is still probably what you want.

[This page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/) has a lot of good examples.

By "context" I'm assuming you want to be able to `cd` into another directory and run commands from there. That's what `fabric.context_managers.cd` is for -- search for it on that page.

Comment: Oh, thats really cool. How about the mysql stuff? Running "mysql -u root" will open up a new mysql console waiting for you to put in commands. Not sure how to handle that.

Comment: Could you instead push down a [mysql script](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) and execute it?

Comment: I think that's perfect actually. I'll just run the 1 command "mysql -u root -e 'sql stuff'" and it should work. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are doing some sort of remote deployment/configuring. There's a whole world of tools out there to professionally set this up, look into Chef and Puppet.

Alternatively if you're just looking for a quick and easy way of scripting some remote commands, maybe pexpect can do what you need.

> Pexpect is a pure Python module for spawning child applications; controlling them; and responding to expected patterns in their output.

I haven't used it myself but a quick glance at its manual suggests it can work with an SSH session fine: https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pxssh.html

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Fabric.

My way to solve those kind of issues (before starting to use saltstack) it was using [pyexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), to run the ssh connection, and all the commands that were needed.
maybe the use of a series of sql scripts to work with the database (just to make it easier) would help.

Another way, since you need to access the remote server using ssh, it would be using [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) to connect and execute commands remotely. It's a bit more complicated when you want to see what's happening on stdout (while with pexpect you will see exactly what's going on).

but it all depends from what you really need.